# How to display logs from grafana's explore in readable way

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I view my logs in grafana and in explore window each field I choose is concatenated into single line, like `foo=value bar=value`. This is example from grafana documentation:
[image]

This quickly becomes unreadable mess, becuase log messages have variable length, and you have more and more of them.

Kibana handles this in readable way by using column for each field:
[image]
All log entries are aligned in table, and header is a the top, so there is less noise overall, and it's very easy to scan over logs and pick up logs I need.

How I can display logs in readable way in grafana's explore tab?

Comment: "each field I choose is concatenated into single line" - no, it's not. Grafana's explore view for logs show full log line stored in the Loki. If you want to parse log line into labels, and show them as table, you'll need to do this in a query, and put result into table panel. AFAIK, tables are not supported for logs in explore view.

Comment: If you use transformer i.e. json parser you can parse it into fields, and you can choose which view you want to see. However these fields are displayed in single line, and not grouped in any way.